# While loop is not performing some task

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I am surprised on php behavior. Initially I wrote this piece of code on retail website. it is supposed to move all products from cart on specific category and after it finished moving it is supposed to delete them from cart. This piece of code works just I wanted but while debuging them I released I put DELETE query inside the while loop and I am surprised. Doesn't the first iteration delete the products from cart and unable to move other products?
So the question why on the first iteration "query2" is not performed?

```
$query=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE category=13544412");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $upc=$row['upc'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    
    $query2=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO paid (upc, name) VALUES ('$upc','$name')");
    if($query2){
        $query3=mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM cart WHERE category=13544412");
    }
}
```

Comment: It probably does delete it, but in the PHP you're still iterating through results which you had fetched into memory before the delete occurred

Comment: oh, I had no idea php used any king of memory. I always thought Php makes new query for each action. Thanks for the answer it changes everything for me. So is it good practice to put Delete query inside while loop or should I take it out?

Comment: No it runs the query once, gets the results into a buffer, and then fetch_assoc fetches rows from the buffer. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: `is it good practice`...that's a matter of opinion and whether it suits what you need.